# custom color for RaisedButton Flutter

Tags: flutter

when i add custom color using this library for RaisedButton 
https://pub.dev/packages/color

```
    return new Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 180.0, 10.0, 0.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 60.0,
          child: new RaisedButton(
            elevation: 5.0,
            // color: Colors.greenAccent[100],
            color:rgbColor,
            // color: Color(0xffFF1744),
            child: new Text( 'Sign in',
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color:Colors.black,fontWeight:FontWeight.w400)),
            onPressed: () => {

            },
          )
```

it gives me this error

```
The argument type 'Color (where Color is defined in /Users/abeer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/color-2.1.1/lib/color.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color (where Color is defined in /Users/abeer/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/ui/painting.dart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use rbgColor from Color library, you can just simply use

```
Color.fromRGBO(r, g, b, opacity)
```

to define the color from rgb you want.

Answer (score 0):

use with brackets

```
Colors. black[50]
```

check issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15658